# Cannot set the selected values in a drop down box from a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a dropdown box on my form which is populated from a MySQL database. When a value is selected i want to open a larger form and set the value selected initially to become the selected value on the new form.

My HTML code for the Combo is as follows

```
<select id ="Opponents" name ="Opponents"
    <?php 
       opponent_load(Wheathill)
    ?>
    >
</select>
```

The PHP function, which is used to populate the dropdown list as well as set the SELECTED value to display, is as follows ;

```
    function opponent_load($oppt){
      $db_handle = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
      $database = "matchmanagementdb";
      $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);
      if ($db_found) {
          $SQL = "SELECT * FROM opponentsdb";
          $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);
          while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $uName = $db_field['Opponents'];
            if ($uName == $oppt) {
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            } else {
                $selected = '';
            }
     echo "<option value='$uName' '$selected'> $uName </option>";
     }
     } else {
            print "Database NOT Found ";
     }
     mysqli_close($db_handle);
     }
```

The new form has the values in the dropdown box BUT the selected value is not shown as Wheathill. I intend to replace the function argument "Wheathill" with a variable that will be defined in another function.
Can anyone help as to why the code does note work.

The code above is part of a larger code which includes a reference to the values required by the mysqli_connect() function

NOTE Novice at PHP.

Comment: echo `$selected`, not `'$selected'`. You can learn this from examining source html code of your page. Also, if you pass string as argument - quote it: `"Wheathill"`

Comment: # u_mulder   You are a star. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors here are the following.

First, you need to call `opponent_load(Wheathill)` **after** closing `>`. Currently, it is **invalid** markup, browser tries to fix it, but it is still invalid.

```
<select id ="Opponents" name ="Opponents">
    <?php  opponent_load(Wheathill); ?>
</select>
```

Second, as you pass a string to a function, it's **reasonable** to enclose string in quotes.

```
<select id ="Opponents" name ="Opponents">
    <?php  opponent_load('Wheathill'); ?>
</select>
```

And third one - is outputing `<option>`:

```
echo "<option value='$uName' '$selected'> $uName </option>";
```

If you put your `$selected = 'selected="selected"';` here you will get:

```
<option value='$uName' 'selected="selected"'> $uName </option>
```

That's definitely an invalid markup. The solution is - remove quotes:

```
echo "<option value='$uName' $selected> $uName </option>";
```

which becomes:

```
<option value='$uName' selected="selected"> $uName </option>
```

which is correct.

Comment: #u_mulder      This works great thank you. I now want to turn the argument into a variable as follows;        player_load(<?php echo $_POST["$OpponentName"]; ?>) but this shows as an error. Any ideas.

Comment: I don't know what is player_load, I don't know what is the error. As a new question and explain the situation.

Comment: #u_mulder Sorry should have been opponent_load(<?php echo $_POST["$OpponentName"]; ?>)         I have a form that I use to get two variables that I use to search a MySQL database. Having found the data I wish to pass the data back to a data entry form containing combos  by defining each combo with a specific 'Selected' value for display. That is I want to replace 'Wheathill' in the above HTML with a variable I get from another PHP script that is included in the HEAD.

Comment: So, you open `<?php` in another opened `<?php`? Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I was not sure  opening one <?php inside another was a good idea. I have moved on a bit. I have set the variable $uOpponents that I wish to use to be global in the first PHP script(Main_PHP_Code.php) and the second script (opponent_load()).  Then used used  opponent_load('$uOpponents') but still fails. Also tried setting opponent_load() without an argument and calling $uOpponets directing in the second script without success.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to __ask another question__.